# Batch file (.bat) to create new folders, move files from multiple subfolders and delete old folders

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I am looking for help writing code that will do the following:

My parent folder will have a varying number of subfolders, with files in each folder.

- C:\Downloaded_Files

  - Job1

    - JobName1.jxl
    - JobName1.job
    - Notes1.pdf
    - File.T02
    - Pic1.jpg
    - Pic2.jpg
  - Job2

    - JobName2.jxl
    - JobName2.job
    - Notes2.pdf
    - File.T02
    - Pic1.jpg
    - Pic2.jpg
  - Etc

I want to create new folders in the parent directory that are named after the .jxl file extension contained in each of the current subfolders, and move all of the files from the previous folder to the new one. I then want the old folders deleted.

- C:\Downloaded_Files

  - JobName1

    - JobName1.jxl
    - JobName1.job
    - Notes1.pdf
    - File.T02
    - Pic1.jpg
    - Pic2.jpg
  - JobName2

    - JobName2.jxl
    - JobName2.job
    - Notes2.pdf
    - File.T02
    - Pic1.jpg
    - Pic2.jpg
  - Etc

I have tried the following code to make the folders:

```
@echo off
pushd C:\Downloaded_Files
for /r %%F in (*.jxl) do (
  2>nul md "%%~nF"
)
popd
```

It makes the new folders, I get proper code to move the files from the old folders to the new ones and then delete the old (empty) folders.

Comment: Why not just rename the original folders? (Also, as always, why not use PowerShell? `gci -Dir | ren -New {(gci "$_\*.jxl")[0].BaseName}`)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have never programmed in PowerShell, so that is completely new to me.